# Combine two or more columns in a dataframe into a new column with a new name

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, r-faq

For example if I have this:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)

  n  s     b
1 2 aa  TRUE
2 3 bb FALSE
3 5 cc  TRUE
```

Then how do I combine the two columns `n` and `s` into a new column named `x` such that it looks like this:

```
  n  s     b     x
1 2 aa  TRUE  2 aa
2 3 bb FALSE  3 bb
3 5 cc  TRUE  5 cc
```

Answer (score 174):

Use  `paste`.

```
 df$x <- paste(df$n,df$s)
 df
#   n  s     b    x
# 1 2 aa  TRUE 2 aa
# 2 3 bb FALSE 3 bb
# 3 5 cc  TRUE 5 cc
```

Comment: .@thelatemail - How to add a special character between data points using `paste()`? For above example, `x` column should have data as `2-aa`, then `3-bb` and `5-cc`.

Comment: .@thelatemail - This worked for me: `paste(df$n,df$s,sep="-")`

Comment: how can you omit NA if column `s` has NA value? (I don't like to see `3 NA` if `df$s[2]=NA`)

Answer (score 55):

For inserting a separator:

```
df$x <- paste(df$n, "-", df$s)
```

Comment: .@LittleBee - This adds a space between two data. Final output for example is like: `A - B` instead of `A-B`. Is it possible to remove this extra space?

Comment: .@LittleBee - This worked for me: `paste(df$n,df$s,sep="-")`

Comment: use paste0  instead of paste

Comment: This won't give the desired output : OP asks for a space in between the elements, not another separator (which, by the way, would be better put as the `sep` argument...). The other answer, posted almost 4 years prior to yours, is however perfectly answering the question.

Answer (score 31):

As already mentioned in comments by Uwe and UseR, a general solution in the `tidyverse` format would be to use the command `unite`:

```
library(tidyverse)

n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 

df = data.frame(n, s, b) %>% 
  unite(x, c(n, s), sep = " ", remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: What is x in this example?

Comment: @Levi, that ``x`` represents the name of the new column that contains the combined values. Think of dplyr's ``mutate``: ``df %>% dplyr::mutate(x = "your operations")``

Comment: Could you please explain why mutate is incorrect but unite is correct? I think this had been explained in comments by Uwe and UseR, but I can't find seem to find those comments--I think they were deleted. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

Using `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, x = paste(n, s)) 

df 
> df
  n  s     b    x
1 2 aa  TRUE 2 aa
2 3 bb FALSE 3 bb
3 5 cc  TRUE 5 cc
```

Comment: No, as already existing answers, you are using *paste*, not *mutate*.

Comment: I thought I was demonstrating how columns could be combined as a part of a `dplyr::mutate()`. Sorry, just trying to be helpful - I won't pollute the site anymore and abstain from future postings.

Comment: Sorry, if it came out as rude. OP's problem is not solved by using *mutate*, question is not about how to use *dplyr*, but how to combine column values. I am simply pointing out that they need *paste* not *mutate*. If we want to demonstrate *dplyr* correct way is [using the function *unite*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860448/680068).

Comment: @zx8754, why mutate is incorrect but unite is correct? The answer you shared has referenced comments by Uwe and UseR, but it looks like those comments have been deleted.

Answer (score 16):

Some examples with NAs and their removal using apply

```
n = c(2, NA, NA) 
s = c("aa", "bb", NA) 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA) 
c = c(2, 3, 5) 
d = c("aa", NA, "cc") 
e = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b, c, d, e)

paste_noNA <- function(x,sep=", ") {
gsub(", " ,sep, toString(x[!is.na(x) & x!="" & x!="NA"] ) ) }

sep=" "
df$x <- apply( df[ , c(1:6) ] , 1 , paste_noNA , sep=sep)
df
```

Comment: @Ferroao Thanks, you saved my life. pls move paste_noNA function before df$x <-apply.

Answer (score 14):

We can use *paste0*:

```
df$combField <- paste0(df$x, df$y)
```

If you do not want any padding space introduced in the concatenated field. This is more useful if you are planning to use the combined field as a unique id that represents combinations of two fields.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of

- `paste` (default spaces),
- `paste0` (force the inclusion of missing `NA` as character) or
- `unite` (constrained to 2 columns and 1 separator),

I'd suggest an alternative as flexible as `paste0` but more careful with `NA`: `stringr::str_c`

```r
library(tidyverse)

# check the missing value!!
df <- tibble(
  n = c(2, 2, 8),
  s = c("aa", "aa", NA_character_),
  b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    paste = paste(n,"-",s,".",b),
    paste0 = paste0(n,"-",s,".",b),
    str_c = str_c(n,"-",s,".",b)
  ) %>% 

  # convert missing value to ""
  mutate(
    s_2=str_replace_na(s,replacement = "")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    str_c_2 = str_c(n,"-",s_2,".",b)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>       n s     b     paste          paste0     str_c      s_2   str_c_2   
#>   <dbl> <chr> <lgl> <chr>          <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr>     
#> 1     2 aa    TRUE  2 - aa . TRUE  2-aa.TRUE  2-aa.TRUE  "aa"  2-aa.TRUE 
#> 2     2 aa    FALSE 2 - aa . FALSE 2-aa.FALSE 2-aa.FALSE "aa"  2-aa.FALSE
#> 3     8 <NA>  TRUE  8 - NA . TRUE  8-NA.TRUE  <NA>       ""    8-.TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

extra note from `str_c` documentation

> Like most other R functions, missing values are "infectious": whenever a missing value is combined with another string the result will always be missing. Use `str_replace_na()` to convert `NA` to `"NA"`

Comment: `paste0(n,"-",s,".",b)` and `str_c(n,"-",s,".",b)` are exactly the same, both use a default separator that is the empty string `''`. I also don't know why `paste` is "tidy", you mean you don't like spaces?

Comment: `paste0` and `str_c` are not exactly the same. take a look to these links: (1) https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_c (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118271/difference-between-paste-str-c-str-join-stri-join-stri-c-stri-pa/53118273#53118273

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks! How they are different would be a good addition to this answer (and the `str_c` documentation could be more explitic too!).

Comment: @Axeman thanks for your suggestion. I've simplified the answer plus added an extra note on the issue

Answer (score 6):

There are other great answers, but in the case where you don't know the column names or the number of columns you want to concatenate beforehand, the following is useful.

```
df = data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = letters[6:10], z = letters[11:15])
colNames = colnames(df) # could be any number of column names here
df$newColumn = apply(df[, colNames, drop = F], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(i) paste(i, collapse = ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to also propose a method for concatenating a large/unknown number of columns. The solution proposed by [Ben Ernest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2242043/ben-ernest) can be pretty slow on large datasets.

Below is my proposed solution:

```
# setup data.frame - Making it large for the time benchmarking
n = rep(c(2, 3, 5), 1000000)
s = rep(c("aa", "bb", "cc"), 1000000)
b = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), 1000000) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)

# The proposed solution:
colNames = c("n", "s") # could be any number of column names here
df$x <- do.call(paste0, c(df[,colNames], sep=" "))

# running system.time on this yields:
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.861   0.005   1.865 

# compare with alternative method:
df$x <- apply(df[, colNames, drop = F], MARGIN = 1, 
                         FUN = function(i) paste(i, collapse = ""))
# running system.time on this yields:
# user  system elapsed 
#  16.127   0.147  16.304
```