# How do you merge tables by ID, then combine cells with the same ID

Tags: r, join

Table1:

```
      ID Sex
1: 12345   M
2: 23456   M
3: 34567   F
4: 45678   F
5: 56789   F
```

Table2:

```
      ID  name
1: 12345   sam
2: 23456  jack
3: 23456   tom
4: 56789 steve
5: 56789   rob
```

I need to merge these two tables to get:

```
   ID Sex      name
1: 12345   M       sam
2: 23456   M  jack,tom
3: 34567   F          
4: 45678   F          
5: 56789   F steve,rob
```

I tried to use the `Join` function but it doesn't allow me to combine those names, is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve]. Show your research and your code, and the results you get. No one will write this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are data.tables, one option would be to `paste` the 'name' by 'ID' in the second dataset 'dt2' and join with the first ('dt1') on 'ID' and create the column 'name' in the first dataset

```
library(data.table)
dt1[dt2[, .(name = toString(name)), ID], name := name, on = .(ID)]
dt1
#      ID Sex       name
#1: 12345   M        sam
#2: 23456   M  jack, tom
#3: 34567   F       <NA>
#4: 45678   F       <NA>
#5: 56789   F steve, rob
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of three separate operations that have been covered in detail in other answers on this site:

1. You want to **join the tables together**:

   - [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1)
2. then **spread from long to wide format**

   - [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format?rq=1)
3. and finally **paste those multiple 'name' columns together into a single name column**

   - [How to combine two or more columns in a dataframe into a new column with a new name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115550/how-to-combine-two-or-more-columns-in-a-dataframe-into-a-new-column-with-a-new-n)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20142834)

Comment: My understanding is that only applies when the links are to outside resources, not to other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: On top of that you did extract the core of what needs to be done then linked to a resource which explains the details. I think that's fair.