# Is there a command to consolidate columns in R?

Tags: r

If my dataframe looks something like this

```
employee <- c('John','Peter','Jolie', 'Susan', 'Mark', 'David')
a <- c(21000, NA, 26800, NA, NA ,NA)
b <- c(NA, 35000, NA, NA, NA, NA)
c <- c(NA,NA,NA,40000, 20000, 45000)
d <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25',NA, NA,'2007-3-14', NA))
e <- as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA,'2014-6-1', NA,'2017-10-15'))
f <- as.Date(c( NA, NA,'2010-3-20',NA, NA, NA))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

is there a way to coerce the data to remove the NAs and consolidate this to three columns? So it would look like:

```
John   21000  2010-11-1
Peter  35000  2008-3-25
Jolie  26800  2010-3-20
Susan  40000  2014-6-1
Mark   20000  2007-3-14
David  45000  2017-10-15
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two or more columns in a dataframe into a new column with a new name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115550/combine-two-or-more-columns-in-a-dataframe-into-a-new-column-with-a-new-name)

Answer (score 2):

An option is `coalesce` from `dplyr` - `coalesce` columns a to c, and d to f separately

```
library(dplyr)
employ.data %>%
     transmute(employee, a = coalesce(a, b, c), 
                        date = coalesce(d, e, f))
```

-output

```
employee     a       date
1     John 21000 2010-11-01
2    Peter 35000 2008-03-25
3    Jolie 26800 2010-03-20
4    Susan 40000 2014-06-01
5     Mark 20000 2007-03-14
6    David 45000 2017-10-15
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
type.convert(as.data.frame(t(apply(employ.data, 1, 
     FUN = function(x) na.omit(x)))), as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned some of the columns overlap. there could be a column like  c <- c('2010-11-1',NA,NA,40000, 20000, 45000)
d <- as.Date(c(NA,'2008-3-25',NA, NA,'2007-3-14', NA))  I know the as.date doesn't make sense here but this is just an example.

Comment: sorry, i'm kind of new to stack overflow and didn't know you need to

Comment: @Stacy I am not sure how different it is from the example in comments.  This `employ.data %>% mutate(across(-employee, as.character)) %>% rowwise %>% transmute(employee, out = list(as.list(na.omit(c_across(-employee))))) %>% ungroup %>% unnest_wider(out, names_repair = ~c("employee", "a", "date")) %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` works if the data is as showed in 'c', 'd'

Comment: @Stacy if the order of occurrence is same i.e. numeric value followed by date (anywhere in the same row), then `type.convert(as.data.frame(t(apply(employ.data, 1, 
     FUN = function(x) na.omit(x)))), as.is = TRUE)` should work as well

Answer (score 0):

this is a base R solution that can also accommodate the above changes in the dataframe. Maybe it is not the best solution in terms of performance but it should work

```r
data_return <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(employ.data), 3))

i_lauf <- 1
tmp <- ""

for(i in 1:nrow(employ.data)) # i=1
{
  if( (ncol(employ.data) - sum(is.na(employ.data[i,]), na.rm = FALSE)) == 3) # chec for 3 entries
  {
    tmp <- ""
    
    for(j in 1:ncol(employ.data))
    {
      if( is.na(employ.data[i,j]) == FALSE)
      {
       if(j == 1)
       {
         tmp <- paste(employ.data[i,j])
       }else{
         tmp <- paste(tmp, employ.data[i,j], sep = "_") 
       }
        i_lauf <- i_lauf + 1
      }
    }
    
    data_return[i, ] <- data.frame(matrix(strsplit(tmp, "_")[[1]], 1, 3))
  }
}
```

Greetings