# How to concatenate column and custom strings in a dataframe R?

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID  GRgroup ARgroup
MB-0000 High    Moderate
MB-0002 Moderate    High
MB-0005 High    High
MB-0006 Moderate    Low
MB-0008 High    Low
MB-0010 High    Moderate
```

I want concatenate 2nd and 3rd column. The expected output is:

```
ID  GRgroup ARgroup ARGR
MB-0000 High    Moderate    AR:Moderate_GR:High
MB-0002 Moderate    High    AR:High_GR:Moderate
MB-0005 High    High    AR:High_GR:High
MB-0006 Moderate    Low AR:Low_GR:Moderate
MB-0008 High    Low AR:Low_GR:High
MB-0010 High    Moderate    AR:Moderate_GR:High
```

I have done this in python as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Concatenate 'GRgroup' and 'ARgroup' columns with the desired format
df['ARGR'] = "AR:" + df['ARgroup'] + "_GR:" + df['GRgroup']

# Reorder the columns
df = df[['ID', 'GRgroup', 'ARgroup', 'ARGR']]
```

How do I do this in R?

Comment: This is not exactly the copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115550/). Here, I need to add custom strings as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` function in R to concatenate:

```
#Concatenate the groups
data$ARGR <- paste("AR:", data$ARgroup, "_GR:", data$GRgroup)

#Reorder
data <- data[, c("ID", "GRgroup", "ARgroup", "ARGR")]
```

or to get it without space between the groups

```
data$ARGR <- paste0("AR:", data$ARgroup, "_GR:", data$GRgroup)
```

Comment: In this output there is space between the `Groups`. I want it like `AR:Moderate_GR:High` without the space

Comment: @biologs paste has `sep` argument, by default it is space.

Comment: you can also use `paste0` to remove the space

Comment: Is it possible to get frequency of each items in the `ARGR` group

Comment: use `as.data.frame(table(data$ARGR))`